# Как можно получить ид странички пользователя вконтакте по номеру телефона?

Tags: vkontakte-api

Наткнулся на интересную функцию

Позвонил компании, сделал заказ и через минуту приходит сообщение Вконтакте о формировании заказа, при этом я информации с ВК им не давал

Как это работает?

Облазил все API, подобной информации нет

Comment: На данный момент получилось выяснить только то, что данная возможность присутствует у подтвержденных групп(с галочкой)

Comment: Вам вместе с сообщением должно было прийти уведомление со ссылкой на подробное описание этого сервиса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тех. Поддержка ВК ответила

Получить ИД по номеру невозможно

Происходит исключительно отправка сообщений, контактную информацию компания не получает, только статус отправки сообщения(Доставлено, Не доставлено)
Данная услуга платная и она доступна только для подтвержденных групп
Вот сам сервис https://notify.mail.ru/